# How to parse specific string from an excel cell (No numbers in cell)?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following data in cells

1 [Chelsea-QPR]
2 [Liverpool-Sunderland]
3 [NewcastleUtd-Everton]

I want to separate the team names into two different cells.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this I used the Text to columns feature under the Data tab and used "-" as the delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

With data in  A2 try this formula in B2

`=MID(A2,2,FIND("-",A2)-2)`

and in C2

`=SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(A2,1,FIND("-",A2),""),"]","")`

Comment: the =mid formula is returning the right text but in all the results the first letter is missing for example helsea, iverpool, ewcastle etc

Comment: I changed the =MID(A2,2,FIND("-",A2)-2) formula to =MID(A2,1,FIND("-",A2)-2)

Comment: I was assuming that the brackets were part of the text in those cells - hence why the MID function used 2 not 1, if the brackets are not there then you can also simplify the second formula , SUBSTITUTE is not required so that becomes just `=REPLACE(A2,1,FIND("-",A2),"")`

Comment: I see, I didn't have time to format the text as cells and columns so I did this in a hurry. I understand. Thanks